# How to extend VpnService to open an L2TP/IPSEC connection in android programmatically?

Tags: android, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I am looking to implement a solution to open a `L2TP/IPSEC` connection from the android application so I can simply pass the `server ip`, `pre-shared key`, `username` and `password` and so the device is connected to this VPN server

I looked here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html that we need to extend and build our own VPN solutions to do that.

Is there any available solutions for that so we can use it instead of reinventing the wheel?

I tried the below implementations of `VpnService` but none of them worked for me

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn
- https://pomgit.com/limeysoft/L2TP-VPN/tree/master/app

And tried this

- https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/vpn/java/android/net/vpn/

and got the below error

> mtpd: Start VPN daemon: mtpd W/libc: Set property "ctl.start" to
>   "mtpd"
>           Unable to set property "ctl.start" to "mtpd": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied) E/SysPropJNI:
>   SystemProperties_set key:ctl.start,val:mtpd W/System.err:
>   java.io.IOException: cannot start service: mtpd W/System.err:     at
>   com.mega.speed.vpn.DaemonProxy.start(DaemonProxy.java:58)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.mega.speed.vpn.VpnDaemons.startDaemon(VpnDaemons.java:92)
>                     at com.mega.speed.vpn.VpnDaemons.startMtpd(VpnDaemons.java:113)
>                     at com.mega.speed.vpn.VpnDaemons.startL2tp(VpnDaemons.java:36)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.mega.speed.vpn.L2tpService.connect(L2tpService.java:16)
>                     at com.mega.speed.fragments.HotspotFragment.onCreateView(HotspotFragment.java:125)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
>                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
>                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
>                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
>                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
>                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
>                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) W/System.err:
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
>                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

Comment: If you are asking "how do I set up the device to use a VPN programmatically from my app?", that should not be possible except perhaps by device admin/device owner apps. If you are asking "how would I do L2TP/IPSEC from my app that is not itself a VPN?", I have no idea, as I have not implemented a VPN.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, so you agree that the only possible way to open a vpn connection is to implement a VPN as we don't have anymore a vpn implementation in android?

Comment: We do have a VPN implementation in Android... for *users*. See Settings > Network & Internet > VPN on Android 9.0, for example.

Comment: yes it's ok for this.. but I mean we don't have a native vpn implementation in android "programmatically", yes?

Comment: Well, that gets back to my original comment. I do not know what you are trying to do: programmatically set up a VPN the way the user can through Settings (hopefully not possible, at least for ordinary apps) or implement a VPN-style protocol in your own app (presumably possible, but I have not done it).

Comment: yes I'm trying to implement a VPN-style protocol in my own app, I found some implemented solutions but it's not working.. thanks

Comment: @JadChahine Have you found any good solution for IPsec/L2TP protocol?

Comment: @NomanAziz unfortunately no ...

Comment: Have you tried with ics-openvpn?

Comment: the requirement asked by the networking team was to use IPsec/L2TP so I didn't tried other things